# The build is failing for IOS in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, build, flutter-build

```
/Users/avinashkasukurthi/Developer/Flutter Projects/zopnote/consumer-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/vv/l96pnk5d49z96x0w400w0r0m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.jlRzPP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dira4jNaQ/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Answer (score 0):

Please goto Podfile inside that check for this line platform :ios, '9.0'
and change that 9.0 to 11.0 or 12.0 if its commented line then uncomment it.
like this
[image]

EDIT

scroll down to end of Podfile and you find something like this
[image]

Add this line :

```
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0
```

or

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0
```

with

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For flutter developers if you are using latest macOS and Xcode version

-Don't try to change anything in Xcode [for example if you already checked Run Script,Thin Binary - "Based on dependency analysis" or "for install build only" then uncheck]

Just try

> Upgrading to latest version - Flutter

Channel stable, 3.7.7 - 3.7.10 etc

suggestion to use IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12 in all places [runner , target runner , pod file ]